# Issues with adding a child node to a parent node in asp.net c# code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to dynamically add a drop-down menu to a panel whenever a user clicks on the button "Add Item". The issue I am running in to is, being unable to add it as a child node to the parent panel located in the asp.net code. At this point whenever I click "Add Item", it just replaces the drop-down menu with a new one and deletes the selected data. If someone could point me in the right direction on how I could append the parent and generate a new drop-down below the previous one on click, that would be great.

[image]

```
<asp:panel ID="AddMealContainer" runat="server">

                </asp:panel>
```

This is where the asp.net is being added:

```
public partial class AddMeal : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)

        {
            ViewState["AddItemCounter"] = 1;
            BindData();
        }
    }

    protected void AddMealButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string AddItemCounter = ViewState["AddItemCounter"].ToString();
        Panel AddItemFormGroup = new Panel();
        AddItemFormGroup.Attributes["class"] = "form-group";
        AddMealContainer.Controls.Add(AddItemFormGroup);
        Panel AddItemRow = new Panel();
        AddItemRow.Attributes["class"] = "row";
        AddItemFormGroup.Controls.Add(AddItemRow);
        Label AddItemLabel = new Label();
        AddItemLabel.Text = "Item";
        AddItemLabel.CssClass = "col-xs-4 control-label";
        AddItemLabel.AssociatedControlID = "AddItemDropDownList_" + AddItemCounter;
        AddItemRow.Controls.Add(AddItemLabel);
        Panel AddItemDiv = new Panel();
        AddItemDiv.Attributes["class"] = "col-xs-4";
        AddItemRow.Controls.Add(AddItemDiv);
        DropDownList AddItemDropDown = new DropDownList();
        AddItemDropDown.ID = "AddItemDropDownList_" + AddItemCounter;
        AddItemDropDown.Attributes["class"] = "form-control";
        AddItemDropDown.Attributes["data-html"] = "true";
        AddItemDropDown.Attributes["data-animation"] = "true";
        AddItemDropDown.Attributes["data-toggle"] = "tooltip";
        AddItemDropDown.Attributes["data-placement"] = "top";
        AddItemDropDown.ToolTip = "<span style ='color:red'>*</span> Select a meal for your training<br>";
        AddItemDiv.Controls.Add(AddItemDropDown);
        Panel AddDivError = new Panel();
        AddDivError.Attributes["class"] = "has-error";
        AddItemDiv.Controls.Add(AddDivError);
        Label AddHasError = new Label();
        AddHasError.Attributes["class"] = "has-error";
        AddDivError.Controls.Add(AddHasError);
        RequiredFieldValidator AddItemValidator = new RequiredFieldValidator();
        AddItemValidator.ID = "AddItemDropdownValidation_" + AddItemCounter;
        AddItemValidator.ControlToValidate = "AddCategoryName";
        AddItemValidator.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
        AddItemValidator.SetFocusOnError = true;
        AddItemValidator.ValidationGroup = "AllValidators";
        AddItemValidator.ErrorMessage = "Category Name is Required";
        AddHasError.Controls.Add(AddItemValidator);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:63591/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("api/Meals/").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            string foodstring = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            List<Meal> editMeal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Meal>>(foodstring);
            Dictionary<int, string> mealDictionary = editMeal.ToDictionary(x => x.MealID, x => x.MealName);
            mealDictionary.Add(0, "--Select--");
            SortedDictionary<int, string> sortedMealDictionary = new SortedDictionary<int, string>(mealDictionary);

            AddItemDropDown.DataSource = sortedMealDictionary;
            AddItemDropDown.DataTextField = "Value";
            AddItemDropDown.DataValueField = "Key";
            AddItemDropDown.DataBind();
        }

        int counterInt = Convert.ToInt32(AddItemCounter);
        counterInt++;
        ViewState["AddItemCounter"] = counterInt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create controls dynamically on demand, [ASP.NET Page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) requires that you re-create these controls on **every** next page postback. Regardless the postback sender.

So, as soon as you added an item, you have to recreate it and add it again on every next page postback. Even if you create the second item, you must recreate the first one (I recommend to do so on the *Init* even) and only after that add the second item (on the button *Click* event).

**Updated**

Encapsulate the whole code that creates an item in a separate method *CreateItem*. Then call this method on every page postback and create items if necessary:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        ViewState["AddItemCounter"] = 1;
        BindData();
    } else {
        int AddItemCounter = onvert.ToInt32(ViewState["AddItemCounter"]);
        if (AddItemCounter > 1){
          for (int i= 1; i < AddItemCounter; i++)
            CreateItem();
        }
    }
}
protected void AddMealButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateItem();
}
```

Comment: Updated my post